# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status in c++

Tags: c++, exit-code, elementary-os

I have just switched to elementary os and installed sublime text editor. i wrote a basic hello world program in c++ to check the working. And I get this error.

```
/tmp/cc3Pmvft.o: In function `main':
source.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `std::cout'
source.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<<  <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
source.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
source.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/cc3Pmvft.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
source.cpp:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
source.cpp:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The hello world program was,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
     cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

I have  searched for answer in google and stackoverflow but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: _"I have searched for answer in google and stackoverflow but couldn't find a solution."_ Really? I recall this having been asked many many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compile it with C++ compiler, not C, g++ for example.

Instead of this

```
gcc source.cpp
```

do this

```
g++ source.cpp
```